# 2 to 1 has_many through relationship in Rails (how to connect three models together)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, relational-database, has-many-through

What would be the best way to connect following three models?

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :submissions
    has_many :creatures, :through => :submissions, :uniq => true
    has_many :teams, :through => :submissions, :uniq => true
end

class Creature < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :team
    has_many :tournaments, :through => :team
end

class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tournament
    belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :creatures
    has_many :submissions
    has_many :tournaments, :through => :submissions
end
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
> team_1.tournaments[0] = tournament_1

> tournament_1.teams[0]
 (returns team_1)

> team_1.tournaments[0].creatures
 (returns [])

> team.tournaments[0].creatures[0] = creature_1

> creature_1.tournaments 
 (returns tournament_1)
```

What is the most efficient way to have a specific creature and a team associated with a specific tournament?

EDIT: The above is the desired behavior.. Current problem is that as soon as I add team to tournament.teams all the creatures in that team automatically have that tournament listed in creature.tournament, while I am trying to make it so that creatures are added to tournament selectively.. Is it at all possible with one join table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Submission should be your join table between `Tournaments`and `Teams`, correct?

```
             Creature [id, team_id]
                             |
                             |
                             |
                       Team [id]
                             |
                             |
                             |
           Submission [id, team_id, tournament_id]  
                                          |
                                          |
                                          |
                              Tournament [id]
```

Model relationships:

```
class Creature < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :tournaments, :through => :team   # this should work since Rails 3.1 or 3.2
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :creatures 
  has_many :tournaments, :through => :submissions
  has_many :submissions
end

class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :tournament
end

class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :teams, :through => :submissions
  has_many :creatures, :through => :teams     # this should work since Rails 3.1 or 3.2
  has_many :submissions
end
```

Now you should be able to call:
`team_1.tournaments[0].creatures`

Comment: Does not quite work for me (Rails 3.1.3): When I do team_1.tournaments[0].creatures I get all the creatures of that team returned, while I am need to get only those submitted to to that tournament... Also I cannot call creature.tourmanents (returns: Could not find the association :teams in model Creature).

Comment: Oh to fix the latter it should be :through => :team rather than teamS (I fixed that above!). Does that work?